# JPQL parameter type error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my current project I'm using hibernate JPA as a persistence library. And I'm getting strange error when setting the parameters to the query.

I have the following:

```
List<Location> loca = JPA.em().createQuery(
    "SELECT location FROM Location as location"
    + " where "
    + "( 6371 * acos(cos(PI() / 180 * :platitude ) * cos(PI() / 180 *location.latitude  ) * "
    + "cos(PI() / 180 *location.longitude  - PI() / 180 *:plongitude ) + sin( PI() / 180 *:platitude) * "
    + "sin(PI() / 180 *location.latitude ) ) ) < :radius")
    .setParameter("radius", 10000.0)
    .setParameter("platitude", new Double(latitude))
    .setParameter("plongitude", new Double(longitude))
    .getResultList();
```

The result error is:

> [IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [43.239474] was not matching type [java.lang.Integer]]

But this value cannot be cast to integer because of loss of precision.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What database are you using? Is the field type in database decimal like? Is the entity attribute you're setting a double?

Comment: I'm using postgresql, yes entity attribute is double, and database field is "double precision".

Comment: Did you tried replacing 180 with 180.0?

Comment: Which parameter is the error referring to?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Hibernate under JPA, you can resolve this problem by using the Hibernate session directly. I had the same problem and couldn't find another way.

The following should work:

```
Session session = (Session) JPA.em().getDelegate();
List<Location> loca = session.createQuery(
    "SELECT location FROM Location as location"
    + " where "
    + "( 6371 * acos(cos(PI() / 180 * :platitude ) * cos(PI() / 180 *location.latitude  ) * "
    + "cos(PI() / 180 *location.longitude  - PI() / 180 *:plongitude ) + sin( PI() / 180 *:platitude) * "
    + "sin(PI() / 180 *location.latitude ) ) ) < :radius")
    .setParameter("radius", 10000.0, new DoubleType())
    .setParameter("platitude", new Double(latitude), new DoubleType())
    .setParameter("plongitude", new Double(longitude), new DoubleType())
    .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA expects a Double type parameter value for :radius. So just update the radius parameter assignment as ;

```
.setParameter("radius", new Double(10000.0))
```

Comment: The value causing the problem is 43.239474